# UIPopoverController throwing exception while trying to initialize

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uipopovercontroller

Hey am new to xcode programming. so this question might sound ridiculous. I am trying out the various features in `UIWebview`. I successfully added the URL text box and search in Google text box. Now, I am trying to allow the user to add bookmarks. For that, I am saving the URL s in an array. However, I want a `UIPopover` view to pop when I click the Bookmark Bar Button item. I keep getting this error while trying to initialize `UIPopoverController`.

```
objPopOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]init ];
```

Any help as to why it is throwing an exception here.

Thanks.

EDIT:

```
- (IBAction)addBookmark:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    BookmarkPopover *objBook = [[BookmarkPopover alloc]init];    
    objPopOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]init ];
    objPopOverController.contentViewController = objBook;
    objPopOverController.delegate = self;
    objPopOverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(180, 120);
    [objPopOverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
}
```

CONSOLE:

```
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".Attaching to process 13287.
Pending breakpoint 1 - "objc_exception_throw" resolved
[Switching to process 13287 thread 0x2303]
[Switching to process 13287 thread 0x207]
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Error in re-setting breakpoint 1:
Catchpoint 2 (throw)Error in re-setting breakpoint 1:
Error in re-setting breakpoint 1:
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb) 

self    ViewController *    0x6829f20
_cmd    SEL 0x4437
sender  UIBarButtonItem *   0x6a33020
objBook BookmarkPopover *   0x68528b0
Registers   (null)  (null)
Vector Registers    (null)  (null)
x87 Registers   (null)  (null)
```

EDIT 2:

I tried initializing the UIView pro grammatically and then adding it, but it still gives me the same error.

```
-(IBAction) buttonAction:(id)sender {

//build our custom popover view

UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

UIView* popoverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 300)];

popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

popoverContent.view = popoverView;

//resize the popover view shown

//in the current view to the view's size

popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(200, 300);

//create a popover controller

self.objPopOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];

//present the popover view non-modal with a
//refrence to the button pressed within the current view
[self.objPopOverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];

//release the popover content
```

}

I still get stuck when ever i initialize my PopOverController.

Comment: Can you post some code and what exception you are getting?

Comment: hey i just edited the question..

Comment: Could we see `self.objPopOverController`? Are you using ARC?

Comment: look at the exception message, it will tell you what's wrong

Comment: //in .h

@property(nonatomic,strong) UIPopoverController *objPopOverController;

in .m 
i just synthesized it.

yeah am using ARC.

Answer (score 0):

You may not initialize a popover controller with `init`. You must specify the content view controller at intialization with `-initWithContentViewController:`. The assertion you triggered that's causing the crash as well as the documentation for `UIPopoverController` will have told you this.

Comment: hey jason i tried initializing it with the below command..

 BookmarkPopover *objBook = [[BookmarkPopover alloc]init];    
  objPopOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:objBook];

still it i get the same error..

Comment: @footyapps27 Is objBook a proper descendant of UIViewController?

Comment: yeah, its a normal UIViewController Class..

I just made changes to the .xib file of BookmarkPopover class. Changed the size of the view to (180,120)

Comment: @footyapps27 what's the actual exception? Press continue in your debugger to step past your breakpoint and get the exception info. Is onjBook possibly nil?

Comment: Single stepping until exit from function objc_exception_throw, 
which has no line number information.

Catchpoint 2 (exception thrown).Single stepping until exit from function __cxa_throw, 
which has no line number information.

It then takes me to the main function where i get "Program received SIGABRT". How do i check whether objBook is nil or not??

Comment: @footyapps27 it should print an assertion string to the console like "index out of bounds" or some such. Try disabling the breakpoint and running. It may be unsafe for the logger to get the write lock and the debugger may be eating that info when stepping.

Comment: I tried running it without the breakpoint. I am directed directly to the main throwing a SIGABRT error.

The debugger looks something like this..

argc int 1

argv char ** 0xbfffecc8

*argv char * 0xbfffedec

**argv char 47 '/'

Registers (null) (null)
$eax int 0x0
$ebx int 0x1562fac
$ecx int 0xbfffe6bc
$edx int 0x9296fc5a
$esp void * 0xbfffec50
$ebp void * 0xbfffeca8
$esi int 0x222e
$edi int 0x58e4
$eip void (*)() 0x22b8
$eflags int 0x286
$cs int 0x17
$ss int 0x1f
$ds int 0x1f
$es int 0x1f
$fs int 0x0
$gs int 0x37
Vector Registers (null) (null)
x87 Registers (null) (null)